# How to find leaf nodes under a subtree using HierarchyId?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

I am maintaining a tree structure using SQL Server 2008 HierarchyId. My table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[HId] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
[Lvl]  AS ([HId].[GetLevel]()) PERSISTED,
[Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL)
```

All the leaf data is not in the same level. I can find out all the leaf records of the table. But i need to find out the leaf data for any given subtree. In other words, i need to "find all subordinates for any given manager who does not manage any other employee".

Sample data:

```
Id Path Lvl Name 
1 / 0 Emp1 
2 /1/ 1 Emp2 
3 /1/1/ 2 Emp3 
4 /1/1/1/ 3 Emp4 
5 /1/2/ 2 Emp5 
6 /1/2/1/ 3 Emp6 
7 /1/2/1/1/ 4 Emp7 
8 /1/2/1/2/ 4 Emp8 
9 /1/2/2/ 3 Emp9 
10 /1/2/2/1/ 4 Emp10 
11 /1/2/2/2/ 4 Emp11 
12 /1/2/2/3/ 4 Emp12 
13 /1/2/2/4/ 4 Emp13 
14 /1/2/2/5/ 4 Emp14 
25 /1/2/3/ 3 Emp15 
26 /1/2/3/1/ 4 Emp16 
27 /1/2/3/2/ 4 Emp17 
28 /1/2/4/ 3 Emp18 
29 /1/2/4/1/ 4 Emp19 
30 /1/2/4/2/ 4 Emp20 
15 /1/3/ 2 Emp21 
16 /1/3/1/ 3 Emp22 
18 /1/3/1/1/ 4 Emp23 
19 /1/3/1/2/ 4 Emp24 
17 /1/3/2/ 3 Emp25 
20 /1/3/2/1/ 4 Emp26 
21 /1/3/2/2/ 4 Emp27 
22 /1/3/2/3/ 4 Emp28 
23 /1/3/2/4/ 4 Emp29 
24 /1/3/2/5/ 4 Emp3
```

Please help me find this.

Comment: Id       Path Lvl Name
1        / 0 Emp1
2 /1/ 1 Emp2
3 /1/1/ 2 Emp3
4 /1/1/1/ 3 Emp4
5 /1/2/ 2 Emp5
6 /1/2/1/ 3 Emp6
7 /1/2/1/1/ 4 Emp7
8 /1/2/1/2/ 4 Emp8
9 /1/2/2/ 3 Emp9
10 /1/2/2/1/ 4 Emp10
11 /1/2/2/2/ 4 Emp11
12 /1/2/2/3/ 4 Emp12
13 /1/2/2/4/ 4 Emp13
14 /1/2/2/5/ 4 Emp14
25 /1/2/3/ 3 Emp15
26 /1/2/3/1/ 4 Emp16
27 /1/2/3/2/ 4 Emp17
28 /1/2/4/ 3 Emp18
29 /1/2/4/1/ 4 Emp19
30 /1/2/4/2/ 4 Emp20
15 /1/3/ 2 Emp21
16 /1/3/1/ 3 Emp22
18 /1/3/1/1/ 4 Emp23
19 /1/3/1/2/ 4 Emp24
17 /1/3/2/ 3 Emp25
20 /1/3/2/1/ 4 Emp26
21 /1/3/2/2/ 4 Emp27
22 /1/3/2/3/ 4 Emp28
23 /1/3/2/4/ 4 Emp29
24 /1/3/2/5/ 4 Emp3

Comment: Please paste it at the end of question itself.. it is difficut to understand here

Comment: add some sample data in the question itself. basically i want to find out all leaf nodes under any given sub tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `IsDescendantOf` function.

eg:

```
declare @manager hierarchyid
select @Manager = HID from employee where --- criteria for given manager

Select *
from employee
where Hid.IsDescendantOf(@manager)=1
```

To find those which manage no others, add

```
and Hid.GetDescendant(null,null) is null
```

Comment: Hi @podiluska, can you please give the complete query or function. i tried this code but it is not returning any result: